# Sum of the exponents of two distinct powers of $10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $10^a$ and $10^b$ represent two, distinct powers of ten nearest in value but not equal to the number $10^{2017}$. What is $a+b$?

Comment: 2015+2016 I guess

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that
$$10^{2017}-10^{2016}=9\cdot 10^{2016},\quad 10^{2017}-10^{2015}=99\cdot 10^{2015}.$$
Moreover if $a\leq 2014<2018\leq b$ then
$$10^{2017}-10^{a}\geq 999\cdot 10^{2014},\quad 10^{b}-10^{2017}\geq 9\cdot 10^{2017}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but I'm having trouble understanding the question itself.

Comment: Is it a^n + b^n = 10^2017, or is each variable almost equal to 10^2017?

Comment: @TauhidNoor Are you still interested in this question?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

WLOG,  $2017>a\ge b, a=b+c,c\ge0$

$$10^{2017-b}-10^c\approx1$$

By observation, both exponents need to be the smallest possible natural numbers as $10^x(10-1)$ is an increasing function